# Jquery mobile adding a button to a page not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am developing a jquery mobile app. I came across a problem where a dynamically added button will not work unless I use `.trigger('create');` but even after adding the trigger even I still have the same problem. This question is asked many many time on this website but all of the answers suggests adding `.trigger('create');` to the code. How can I fix this problem?
This is my code:

```
var button = $("<a data-role="button" id="my_button">My Button</a>");
$("#my_div").append(button).trigger('create');

$("#my_button").on("click", function(){
    alert("clicked");
});
```

when I click the button nothing happen.

Comment: Have you tried my answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding *anchors* dynamically, use `.buttonMarkup()` to create it. It is possible *not* to add `data-role="button"` when creating it using the aforementioned enhancement method.

```
$("#my_div").append($("<a/>", {
    id: "my_button",
        "data-role": "button"
}).text("Button").buttonMarkup({
    icon: "delete",
    iconpos: "notext"
}));
```

Binding event to dynamically created elements, should be delegated from *document*.

```
$(document).on("click", ".selector", function () {
  alert("clicked");
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/NbE4d/)**

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
var button = $("<button data-role="button" id="my_button">My Button</button>");
```

to:

```
var button = $("<button data-role='button' id='my_button'>My Button</button>");
```

You're not create your button properly. Concatenate your HTML correctly and your code should work

Comment: I changed button to a

Comment: This is my actual code `$("#my-interests-content").append('<div class="my-interests-div">'+titel_value+'<a href="" id="my_button" class="'+value+'" data-icon="delete" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; margin-left:10px;"></a></div>').trigger("create");`

Comment: what is `titel_value` and `value` in your code. Can you clarify?

Comment: `$.each(features_cats, function(index, value){
var titel_value = value.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {return letter.toUpperCase();}).replace(/\-/g, ' ');`
//code here
});

Comment: then what's `features_cats`. Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: features_cats is an array.